# Why won't the dialog box come up when I run this code in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

Please see my code below, why won't the input dialog box come up in Eclipse when I run the program?

```
package cookieTest;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CookieCalories
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
{
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int cookiesEaten = input.nextInt();
        int caloriesPerCookie = 300 / 4;
        int calorieIntake = cookiesEaten * caloriesPerCookie;

        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many cookies did you eat?");

        System.out.print("Your calorie intake was: " + calorieIntake);

        input.close();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well...for one you're prompting the user for the information after you're telling the scanner to get it from input.  That's the first thing I think you should reconsider.

Comment: I structured it how you suggested and now I got my dialog box but no output after entering the input.

Comment: I didn't say that would fix it, I just mentioned that it's something that should be changed for any number of reasons.

Comment: That's fine haha, I was just hoping you would know what to do next.

Comment: I gave a full answer with a fixed line of code, I was able to get it to work with what you have.

Answer (score 1):

So in this case, how you're calling the input dialog and getting the data is not correct, it should look like this:

```
int cookiesEaten = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How many cookies did you eat?"));
```

You don't need a scanner when using the `JOptionPane.showInputDialog()` function as the input dialog handles the scanner.  As for the leading `null` parameter, because we're not dealing with a custom built `Swing` GUI, we don't have a parent.  But `Java` expects one, calling it explicitly and giving it the null parent allows it to open the pane.  (Without it, the program just hangs there forever it seems).

EDIT: Keep in mind, `JOptionPane` takes some time to open the window sometimes.  (roughly 10-15 seconds for me).

Your code should look like this:

```
package cookieTest;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CookieCalories
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int cookiesEaten = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How many cookies did you eat?"));
        int caloriesPerCookie = 300 / 4;
        int calorieIntake = cookiesEaten * caloriesPerCookie;

        System.out.print("Your calorie intake was: " + calorieIntake);

        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```